# Does NSSet's containsObject: test for pointer equality or value equality?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, collections, foundation, nsset

Say I have an `NSSet` with a string in it. If I send `containsObject:` with another string which is a different pointer but the exact same string value, will that return `YES`?

Also, is it the same story when it comes to `removeObject:`? I.e., different objects with different pointers but the same string values will cause removal?

Comment: Did you try it? Do you have any reason to believe that it wouldn't?

Comment: If it considered that two strings with the same content were the same object, you could not get the second string into the set so the removeObject: part of the question is moot.  NSSet claims to provide "static sets of distinct objects" - not "static sets of non-equal objects".

Comment: Yes this works. Can confirm containsObject tests for equal strings. I used it to optimize core data updates so I don't have to look up an entity every time to see if it exists. I just use my key field which is a string.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`-containsObject:` uses `-isEqual:` (and `-hash`) for equality testing. This applies to `-removeObject:` as well, and any other operations in `NSSet` that depend on some notion of equality.

Comment: Where is this documented?  From what I can see, CFSet is clear that it uses POINTER equality by default, but I don't see NSSet clarifying what it uses?

Comment: @user: The [`-[NSSet member:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000143-CHDCHEDC) documentation says that it uses `isEqual:`; `member` is one of [the fundamental set methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Sets.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000136-SW3), and it seems to be implied (though, you're right, not explicit) that `containsObject:` uses `member`.

Comment: @user256413: All NSSet method that rely on equality must, by definition, use the same equality test. CFSet will use the pointer equality *if you don't specify another equality function*. If you use `kCFTypeSetCallBacks` then it uses `CFEqual()` as the equality comparison.

Comment: Thanks, i was hoping that it used isEqual. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Can someone please explain this (apologies for the formatting):
`NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"];`
    `NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObject:str];`
    `NSLog(@"%d", [set containsObject:str]); // returns 1`
    `[str appendString:@"BLA"];`
    `NSLog(@"%d", [set containsObject:str]); // returns 0`
    `NSLog(@"%d", [set.allObjects containsObject:str]); // returns 1`

Comment: @jowie: `NSSet` is a hash table. `-[NSMutableString hash]` depends on the contents of the string. Mutating the string when it's in the set is explicitly unsupported (same as mutating it when it's in an `NSDictionary`), because that changes the hash, which makes lookup fail. However, `set.allObjects` produces an `NSArray` which does not use `hash`.

Comment: Interesting that it changes the hash. Why does it do that?

Comment: @jowie: Because the alternative is for every single `NSMutableString` to have the same hash, which would produce absolutely *abysmal* performance when stored in dictionaries/sets. The simple rule is you're not supposed to mutate an object that's been placed into an `NSSet` or used as the key for an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: So would it be a correct analogy to say that an `NSSet` is like a key-only `NSDictionary` (in the same way that an `NSArray` is a bit like a value-only `NSDictionary`)? Because `NSSet` items are unique, a bit like `NSDictionary` keys?

Comment: @jowie: An `NSSet` is effectively an `NSDictionary` that has no value, that's correct. But no, an `NSArray` is nothing like a value-only `NSDictionary` (besides all the performance differences, `NSDictionary`s are unsorted and `NSArray`s are sorted).